# How to immediately execute an event

Tags: events, stored-procedures, transactions, firebird, firebird2.5

There is a stored procedure in my database which executes a query and populates a table with the results.

Since the loop over the query's results takes a significant amount of time, I tried to **post events via [`post_event`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-postevent) statement**.

A (reasonable) drawback of events in Firebird is that they are not executed until the transaction is committed ([see this PDF](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf)):

> After event is posted, every client that subscribed for it will get the notification. In order for that to happen a separate Firebird's component called Event Manager is running in background, and maintains a list of applications and events they registered to receive. The event is sent to Event Manager only when the transaction inside which the trigger or stored procedure was run is committed.

But I am in the middle of executing a time-consuming stored procedure. So, I need the events to be executed immediately.

Thus, I tried to **post the events using [`in autonomous transaction do`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-autonomous-trans.html)**. Unfortunately, this does not help because

> Autonomous transactions have the same isolation level as their parent transaction.

My next approach was to **go *even more autonomous* using [`execute statement`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html) with options [`with autonomous transaction`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-with-trans) and [`on external`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-on-external)**. For that, I wrote a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXECUTE_STATEMENT_EXTERNAL (
  STATEMENTTEXT TYPE OF DMN_SQLSTATEMENTS)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE ATTACHMENT_NAME TYPE OF DMN_RDB_ATTACHMENTNAME;
begin
  select MON$ATTACHMENT_NAME
    from mon$attachments
    where MON$ATTACHMENT_ID = CURRENT_CONNECTION
    into :attachment_name;

  execute statement statementtext
    with autonomous transaction                  
    on external '127.0.0.1:' || :attachment_name 
    as user '<my user name>'                     
    password '<my password>';                          
end
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, either. Additionally, it significantly slows down the calling stored procedure.

---

So, after all what I have tried, is there anything that lets the events be executed immediately?

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected that to work. Are you using SuperServer, Classic or SuperClassic?

Comment: I use ClassicServer mode, normally.

Comment: I suggest you also ask on the Firebird-support or maybe Firebird-devel mailing list.